# After trying to make a partition bootable in LINUX, the whole hard drive became RAW

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raw

Guys I have a MAJOR problem and I need your help ASAP!

I have windows 10 with an internal HDD drive of 100GB (5 GB is free of that). 
Additionally, I have an external HDD drive of 1TB (NTFS). 
I wanted to install Ubuntu as well. So:

```
1) I made a partition (36 GB) in the external 1TB HDD drive, and I formatted it in 
exFAT (because it was NTFS). 

2) I used YUMI to take the Ubuntu iso file that I have downloaded and make the small
partition (36 GB) bootable to Ubuntu.

3) In the middle of the process of making the small partition bootable, an error popped up,
that I do not have enough free space (probably meaning in the internal hard drive which had
only 5 GB free). 

4) After that, the whole 1TB HDD drive became unrecognisable and I can only see it in disk
management, where it is listed as a whole drive (and not two partitions) and it is 
marked as RAW.
```

Please tell me I did not format my whole drive and please tell me how to recover the drive.

Comment: This does not sound like you formatted your whole drive.  You mentioned this is 1TB, so it might be using MBR.  In that case, you likely just need to fix the data stored in the MBR.  If you're using GPT, this method of fixing may be a bit different, but it does look like most of your data is recoverable.  Causing further damage will be very easy, particularly when making the types of changes that you'll need to make to fix this.  Making a "bit-for-bit" ("forensic") image of the whole drive is recommended before fixing.  If so, probability of 100% recovery being possible seems pretty high.

Comment: Actually, the most concerning step I see is the step number 4 that you've taken.  Disk management?  Did you boot Windows with this drive in the system?  Windows might try to "make sense" of the data by using techniques, including writing to a drive that looks like may have corrupt meta-data.  If that already happened, you may have already lost some key information.  Can you get a backup before attempting any further changes?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just went to Disk management to see if windows recognise this partition at all. Because i could not see it anywhere else. Of course I didn't mess with anything over there. And it recognises it. But without letter (G:, E:, etc) and it is marked as raw. The "format" of the small partition, actually didn't take long before popping the error. So, I guess it wasn't formatted. I believe the problem is that somehow these two partitions were merged into one, and because the big is in NTFS and the small in exFAT, that confuses windows.

Comment: Should I plug the hard drive into a linux environment to see if at least Linux recognises it or better not?

Comment: After getting it backed up, I think that's a step likely to be more worthwhile than using Microsoft Windows's Disk Management.  Microsoft Windows's Disk Management might seem easier, but when using MBR, Linux fdisk could be more clear (than Disk Management) regarding what partitions do/don't currently exist.

Comment: So. I just booted from a live usb Linux ubuntu. I am trying to mount the drive manually (with NTFS) but I receive an error saying "it does not have a valid NTFS flag". The drive as I said has two partitions. One in NTFS and one in exFAT. Any suggestions? Please be my savior

Comment: I suggest showing the partitions here.  (Edit your question, and add text that is copied-and-pasted from the the disk partitioning software.  If you're using MBR-based, this would be the output of fdisk.)

Comment: After working on it two days (actually I got sick from that) on testdisk, I resolved it. I googled testdisk, I downloaded it and I followed its tutorial in every step. Thanks for your help!